# Logo for site will not show up in IE8

Tags: image, internet-explorer-8

I have made a site in wordpress and cannot get the logo in the top nav to show up on IE 8. It works in IE 7 and IE 9 and 10. The site is drdanastern.com

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated

Thanks!!

Comment: It would be nice if you could add the specific lines of code to the question. Some ppl don't want to crawl through your whole site to find a tiny mistake between 100000 of lines of code.

Comment: When I set the browser mode to IE8 it works for me.  Have you cleared your cache?

Comment: The browser mode is fine, it's when you change the document mode to IE8 standards...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I altered the css and was able to see the image when in IE8 document mode.

remove `max-width:100%;` from the `IMG` css class.

After doing so, make sure the rest of your site has not been altered by this. I think you should be OK though.